# Handling terminal command within python file

Tags: python

I write the following code (that are basically terminal commands) in a .py file.

```
import os    
os.system("modtool newmod project")
os.chdir("/home/comp/project")
os.system("modtool add -t general mycode")
```

First two commands works fine but the third command asks some questions i.e. arguments and destination path. Is there any way that we can provide the answer of those question from inside the .py file.

Comment: In most unix systems you can have a command get input from a file by adding "< filename" to the command.

Comment: The hereis document trick might or might not work here.  The idea is you have something like "modtool add -t general mycode <<EOF \nInput Line 1\nInput Line 2\nEOF\n" as your command string.  Whether this works depends on whether everything from os.system in python is handed to the shell as-is. It is a trick that works in shell script files in Bash. Python may have something like this for embedding data in files.

Comment: It is perfectly working Thanks